# how to consuming webservice with Integrated Windows Authentication using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, windows, xmlhttprequest, windows-authentication

Can any body give, how to consume web service with integrated windows authentication using xmlhttprequest?

Comment: which language and platform are you programming in?

Comment: VBA or Java Script , Platform Os-  Windows

Comment: [Simply use the Web Services Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140268(v=office.10).aspx)